# UISlider crashes app when adding programmatically to view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have a custom overlay for camera, it that overlay I have **UISlider**:

```
@implementation LWOverlayView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame imagePath:(NSString*) imagepath{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Clear the background of the overlay:
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


        UIImageView *overlayGraphicView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        overlayGraphicView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        [overlayGraphicView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagepath]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];


        overlayGraphicView.frame = CGRectMake(80, 140, 160, 120);
        [self addSubview:overlayGraphicView];

        UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 436, 320, 44)];
        [toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismiss)];

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);
        UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
        slider.maximumValue = 50.0;
        slider.continuous = YES;
        slider.value = 25.0;


        [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, slider, nil]];

        [self addSubview:toolbar];

    }
    return self;
}
```

App crashes:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISlider view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20854fe0'
```

Any hints?

Comment: Which line does it crash at when you set an `Exception Breakpoint`?

Comment: When does it crash? [toolbar setItems:[NSArrayarrayWithObjects:doneButton, slider, nil]]; ?

Comment: @foFox yep, it crashes there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you can't directly add a `UISlider` (or any other `UIView`) directly to the list of toolbar items.

What you need to do is create a `UIBarButtonItem` that contains the slider.

```
UIBarButtonItem *sliderBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustonView:slider];
```

Now add `sliderBtn` to the array instead of `slider`.

You may find you need to set the `width` property on `sliderBtn`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add the slider to the toolbar:

```
[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, slider, nil]];
```

That is what is breaking your code, you can only add UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar can have items that are UIBarButtonItem. UISlider is not a UIBarButtonItem. That can have something to do with the crash. Try removing the slider and see how it works.