# Adding UISegmentedControl to a UINavigationController's toolBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Trying to add a `UISegmentedControl` into a `UINavigationController`'s toolbar

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = FALSE;

    UIBarButtonItem *test1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Groups"
                                                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                    target:self
                                                                    action:@selector(done)];

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Groups", @"Regions", @"Objects"]];
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

    [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:test1, segmentedControl, nil]];
}
```

This causes the error:

```
-[UISegmentedControl view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x295623c0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISegmentedControl view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x295623c0'
```

If I omit the `UISegmentedControl`, it loads fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to wrap the UISegmentedControl in a UIBarButtonItem with something like `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: segmentedControl]]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISlider crashes app when adding programmatically to view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611452/uislider-crashes-app-when-adding-programmatically-to-view)

Comment: Note that the duplicate question isn't exactly the same but the answer is the same.